# Custom Post Conditional for Parent & Child Single.php?

Tags: custom-post-types, conditional-tags

Following on from previous question but needs to be more specific so thought a new topic would be best...

Conditional tag for custom post parent and children on their corresponding single.php, currently i have the following..

```
    <?php if ( is_home() || is_page( 'overview' ) || is_page( 'about' )  ) : ?>
        Home Page
    <?php elseif ( 'artists' == get_post_type() ): ?>
        artist parent               
    <?php elseif ( $post->post_parent > 0 ): ?> 
     artist   child
    <?php else : ?>
     empty other pages etc

   <?php endif; ?>
```

The issue being the parent shows up on all the single-artists.php pages.

I need to specifically target the parent single and the child single, is it possible as i don’t think it is...?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you should change the order to first check if there is any parent:

```
<?php if ( is_home() || is_page( 'overview' ) || is_page( 'about' )  ) : ?>
    Home Page
<?php elseif ( $post->post_parent > 0 ): ?> 
 artist   child
<?php elseif ( 'artists' == get_post_type() ): ?>
    artist parent               
<?php else : ?>
 empty other pages etc
```